# How to write query for multiple table level search in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to search and fetch data from multiple tables. If I search as "A" it should consider from all table columns, and give the results.

In a query, I need below fields

```
emp_name, emp_age, emp_bank_account, emp_bank_name, emp_nominee_name, emp_nominee_relation
```

My Tables and its field as follows

- Employee with fields (emp_id, emp_name, emp_age)
- EmployeeBankDetails with fields (emp_bank_account,emp_bank_name, emp_id)
- EmployeeNominee with fields (emp_nominee_name, emp_nominee_relation, emp_id)

Please help and thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a query but it is not the best practice to do so.Using many ORs and beginning wildcard characters are killers for performance(https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-optimize-mysql-queries-for-speed-and-perfor)).But if you don't care about performance and practices or may be if the query is for your understanding,then here you go.

```
SELECT T1.emp_id,T1.emp_name,T1.age,T2.emp_bank_account,T2.emp_bank_name,T3.emp_nominee_name,T3.emp_nominee_relation
FROM Employee T1 
INNER JOIN EmployeeBankDetails T2 ON T1.emp_id=T2.emp_id
INNER JOIN EmployeeNominee  T3 ON T1.emp_id=T3.emp_id 
WHERE T1.emp_id LIKE '%A%' OR T1.emp_name LIKE '%A%' OR T1.age LIKE '%A%' OR T2.emp_bank_account LIKE '%A%' OR T2.emp_bank_name LIKE '%A%' OR T3.emp_nominee_name LIKE '%A%' OR T3.emp_nominee_relation LIKE '%A%';
```

Hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: Yep, The count of the items are very less. So it's fine.